# creating a soccer ball with 2d drawing c#

Tags: c#, polygon

I have tried making this for inside the ball and the ball but I don't know how to fill the ball with the GraphiPath I created

```
private void soccerball_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics soccerballg = e.Graphics;
    GraphicsPath hexagon = new GraphicsPath();
    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
    SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
    Point[] points = new Point[]{
        new Point(100,100),
        new Point(108,100),
        new Point(114,106),
        new Point(108,112),
        new Point(100,112),
        new Point(94,106)
    };
    hexagon.AddPolygon(points);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 250, 250);
    hexagon.AddEllipse(rect);

    soccerballg.DrawPath(pen, hexagon);        
    soccerballg.FillRectangle(interior, rect);
}
```

Comment: You want to fill the ball with lines that use relative-coordinates to ball's center? You may need to use a rotation matrix if your ball is rotating. Translation is easier.

Comment: Have you tired anything yet?

Comment: thanks for your comments it is true that i don't work on this for paycheck cause thats gone i just created lots of line inside of ball and made it a soccer ball and sold it but i never satisfied with result now that i am waiting on another problem to be solved here i must say i was shocked how i still can't solve this problem after all i achieved lol never mind . first of we need just one graphic shape and both hexagon and rect will be addpath to it but it doesn't work either so i think if we could give circular outline border to GraphicPath then repeat hexagons with for in maybe works thanks